# Почему не передается коллекция на сторону клиента

Tags: node.js

Создаю map объект и записываю в качестве ключа id, в качестве значения имя пользователя, на стороне сервера все работает хорошо, коллекция выводится в консоль, но когда передаю на сторону клиента, то либо не правильно передается, либо вообще не работает.
Сервер:

```
socket.on('connect user', (userName) => {
    //users.push(userName.userConnect);
    users.set(id++, userName.userConnect); // map users
    console.log(users);
    io.emit("users", users); // passing the collection
```

Клиент:

```
const addUserToModalWindow = () => {
    const contentWindow = document.querySelector(".usersList");
    socket.on('users', (users) => {
    for (let user of users) {
        console.log(user);
        }
    });
};
```

Пишет ошибку:users is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Map нормально не сереализуется. Можешь сделать из него двумерный массив, а на клиенте пересозхдать словарь.

```js
var map = new Map([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

console.log(JSON.stringify(map))
console.log(JSON.stringify([...map.entries()]))
```